# how to highlight an item in listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, highlight

I'm trying to Drag from listView1 and drop on listLocal **which both of them are ListView**
It's a file transfer application between client and server, the application shows small local file explorer **listLocal** and remote file explorer **listView1**.
 so when I drop the items from **listView1** to **listLocal** and the pointer points on an item[**Folder**] it should be highlighted `item.Selected = true`.

but it doesn't work, I tried to do `listLocal.Focus` and `listLocal.Select` still not working, how could I make it work ?

note : when I used `item.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;` it worked, but it doesn't highlight the icon.

```
   private void listLocal_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem))) return;
      Point p = listLocal.PointToClient(MousePosition);
      ListViewItem targetItem = listLocal.GetItemAt(p.X, p.Y);
      if (targetItem != null)               //if dropping on a target item
      {
        targetItem.Selected = true;
        if (targetItem.SubItems.Count > 1) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;//if IsFile
        else e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        return;
      }
      foreach (ListViewItem item in listLocal.Items) item.Selected = false; //if dragging into current address
      e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
```

Comment: Set the HideSelection property to False

Comment: @HansPassant you should post your comment as an answer to let the question to be marked as answered !! right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the HideSelection property to False

Answer (score 0):

You may try to handle the DragOver method.
or have a look at example from microsoft: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.insertionmark(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: while this link may answer the question. It is important to put essential parts of the answer in the post. [from Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11982391)