# Listview drag and drop has no visual highlight on the destination

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm new to a legacy win forms app. It has a list view with a files and folders structure. I want to allow the user to drag file/s to a folder. When I do it I want to find the destination (to do this I find the item at x and y) but to also give the user a visual representation that they are dropping it on a folder (like in windows explorer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377749/how-to-highlight-an-item-in-listview

Comment: You can use the dragenter event to add clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within private void myListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) I tweaked the code in your comment @HansPassant

```
var wPos = this.myListView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
var targetItem = myListView.GetItemAt(wPos.X, wPos.Y);
if (targetItem != null)
{
      var targetNodeInfo = targetItem.Tag as WindowsExplorerModel;

      if (targetNodeInfo != null)               //if dropping on a target item
      {
           if (targetNodeInfo.isFile)               
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;//if IsFile                    
           else
           {
                foreach (ListViewItem listItem in myListView.SelectedItems)
                        listItem.Selected = false;

                targetItem.Selected = true;
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            return;
      }                                
}
```